# Mystery type mismatch while dealing with ASP

Tags: sql-server, arrays, asp-classic

I've never developed in ASP in my life, but a client wants some additional functionality in one of his really terrible ASP programs extended.  I've tried to pick up as much as I can in a short period of time, but I'm running into a mystery bug here.

When I unit-test this code on my local system, it works fine.  On their webserver, however, when executing the below code, I get a type mismatch on the line "Item_IDs = ..."

Any suggestions?

Thanks!
-Drew

```
Item_IDs = RetrieveSerialItem_IDs(Serial_IDs(y))

function RetrieveSerialItem_IDs(Serial_ID)

    '' # Execute query and return data in an array
    strQuery = "SELECT Item_ID FROM Store_Items_Serials WHERE Serial_ID = " & Serial_ID & ";"
    RetrieveSerialItem_IDs = RunSelectQuery(strQuery, "Item_ID")

end function '' # RetrieveSerialItem_IDs

'' # Function to execute a SELECT query from our database
'' # returns: the results of the query as a one-dimensional array -- do not use for multiple-column select statements
function RunSelectQuery(strSelectQuery, strColumnName)
```

Comment: I also just remembered something potentially relevant.  Item_IDs gets written to repeatedly in the context of a for loop.  Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: Paste the complete error message. The phrase "type mismatch" doesn't tell anything about where the error actually occurs.

Comment: @Guffa I would, but the other contractor this company hired has totally hosed the webserver for the time being.  I'm stuck debugging this on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my book, 90% of the time, this kind of error are because the sql is bad.

Other problem that I see, is that you **are not declaring your variables** (maybe it is required in the server and not in your dev machine)

How to debug in ASP classic:

```
Item_IDs = RetrieveSerialItem_IDs(Serial_IDs(y))

function RetrieveSerialItem_IDs(Serial_ID)

    ''//Please, declare your variables
    dim strQuery

    ''//Execute query and return data in an array
    strQuery = "SELECT Item_ID FROM Store_Items_Serials WHERE Serial_ID = "
    strQuery = strQuery  & Serial_ID & ";"

    response.write strQuery
    response.end

    ''// Now, paste the StrQuery text obtained in your sql console and test it


    RetrieveSerialItem_IDs = RunSelectQuery(strQuery, "Item_ID")

end function
```

Comment: Ah, the not declaring my variables was a holdover from PHP.  I will do this from now on.

Answer (score 0):

If the same query string variable get's used more than once classic ASP treats it as a comma separated list.

So a URL of foobar.asp?id=1&id=2&id=3 means the id variables ends up as "1,2,3" - a string, not an array.